# IBAction for UIButton with Custom Type is getting more Delay

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimage, interface-builder

I am using UIButton inside UITextField, setting image for that, setting the Type as Custom in IB, for this button the IBAction method is firing after 2 or 3 seconds only, But for another UIButton, i am setting same image for that, setting the Type as System, for the the IBAction method is fired as normal without any delay.

In System type the image is getting blue color, in Custom type only the image is not changing to blue color. I do not want to change my image color.

Checked SO, but i did not get any posts related to this issue.

Image turning to blue color in system type
[image: image turning to blue color in system type]

Comment: what is your exact question. Can you explain it?

Comment: 1. why the action method is firing with 2 or 3 seconds deley in custom type and 2. Is there any way to change the color of image in System type

Comment: button turns to blue because the default tint color of the button is blue

Comment: Which `ControlEvent` you have chosen for `CustomType`

Comment: Ok, Now i changed the tint color to white, i am unable to see the image now. And even i tried with clear color for Tint color. @Khushbu

Comment: how can you see the white image in white background? Please check with different color.

Comment: I gave Touch Up Inside control event for CustomType @SyedQamarAbbas

Comment: I got it @Khushbu Thanks :) hm do you any idea why in custom type the action method is getting called with delay.

Comment: @R.Mohan I think delay is for another reason. It should not be the issue of button type.

Comment: @Khushbu Yes, delay is due to the image, if i am not setting image for the button, it is fast as usual. Is that the behavior of UIButton with Image in Custom Type.

Comment: Are you setting same image in both custom and system types of button?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170697/discussion-between-r-mohan-and-khushbu).